# AWS VPN Client - "Unknown error ocurred. Try again"

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn

I'm experiencing a persistent issue with the AWS VPN Client and need some assistance. Despite numerous troubleshooting attempts, I'm unable to establish a connection and fail even before reaching the authentication steps. Connecting to the same network with the same settings, my laptop connects perfectly so I am sure something more specific is happening with the desktop, but sadly I am out of ideas about what could be causing it.

Steps taken:

1. Uninstall and Reinstalled AWS VPN Client (even done a registry clean up)
2. Even tried upgrading and downgrading the version of AWS VPN Client I am on version 3.11.0
3. Disabled Firewall and any window defender
4. Disconnect and reconnect the Tap Adapter
5. Ensure all tap adapters get the IP address and DNS server address automatically
6. I have performed a clean boot to ensure that no other programs are interfering with it.
7. Tested it in compatibility mode.

C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\AWSVPNClient\logs

````
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionInitiator.GetPipeName(Uri uri, IPipeTransportFactorySettings transportFactorySettings)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.NamedPipeConnectionPoolRegistry.NamedPipeConnectionPool.GetPoolKey(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationPool`2.TakeConnection(EndpointAddress address, Uri via, TimeSpan timeout, TKey& key)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open()
   at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnWpfProcessManager.CreateWcfChannel()
2024-01-04 16:37:31.091 +11:00 [DBG] WCF channel is in Faulted. Not usable for communication. Sleeping 500 ms before creating a new one```
````